# Firefox displaying a table when IE correctly isn't

Tags: javascript

Here is the code for the beginning portion of the table that should not be showing in firefox

```
<FORM Name='Main' METHOD=POST><!--    DISPLAY PAY PERIOD DETAIL WEEKLY VIEW --><span align='center' id='spanDetails'
                                                                                     style='display:none'><TABLE
        align='center' BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=4 CELLSPACING=0 CLASS=cTable>
    <TR>
        <th CLASS=TH1 align='center' valign='top' colspan='6'>Pay Period Detailss</th>
        <th CLASS=TH1 align='center' valign='top'>
            <style type="text/css">.myLayersClass {
                position: relative;
                display: table;
            }</style>
            <span id='spanHideDetails' class='myLayersClass' style='display: table'><a
                    href='javascript:if (typeof(document.forms["Main"]["showtb"])=="object"){ SetDetailSpanStatus(document.forms["Main"]["showtb"],0);}ToggleDisplay("spanDetails", "");javascript:ToggleDisplay("spanPPDates", "TsLinks");'>Hide</a></span>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <TH ALIGN='center' valign='center'>Date</TH>
        <TH ALIGN='center' valign='center'>Duration</TH>
        <TH ALIGN='center' valign='center'>Title Code/<br>Pay Code</TH>
        <TH ALIGN='center' valign='center'>Project/<br>Enterprise Project</TH>
        <TH ALIGN='center' valign='center'>FAU Title/<br>Shift</TH>
        <TH ALIGN='center' valign='center'>Message</TH>
        <TH ALIGN='center' valign='center'>View</TH>
    </tr>
    <tr CLASS='bottom'>
```

Comment: You did not properly format your code. I went to do it, but it is one giant blob and I do not feel like being your personal assistant.

Comment: Edit your code so we can see it please.

Comment: might want to post working code in a jsfiddle.

Comment: Do you have an ending span tag?

Answer (score 1):

It might just have something to do with that `<span>` with `display: none;` that's wrapped **around your entire table**.

The reason it behaves unexpectedly between browser is usually caused by **invalid HTML**. In all HTML versions other than HTML5, it is invalid for a `<table>` to be inside of a `<span>`. Hence, some browsers will accept it, some will kick the table out of the `<span>`, leaving an empty, invisible span, with a large table outside of it.

Conclusions:

- Use a `<div>`
- Validate your HTML.

Comment: That doesnt explain why firefox shows the table?

Comment: @jtheman: It doesn't for me. What version?

Comment: Well that is the subject anyway...

Comment: @jtheman: What version of firefox are you using?

Comment: I don't. I just read the question. FF normally renders more strict than IE so that coding errors sometimes are ignored on IE but not on FF... My best guess for answering this.